# Use Server php values in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, server-side

This question is because I have some values in a database table that works as parameters, so the approach I think to use them in javascript without using inline scripts was call a `parameters.php` that returns all the values and stores them in javascript `global` variables to use them.
I just want to know if this is correct or if there is better way how to do this.

Comment: If it works, it works.  Just be sure you aren't displaying data you don't want to be displayed.  Your other option is AJAX queries, but if this works and it suits your needs, then use it.

Comment: Why don't you want to do it via an inline script?

Comment: I don't want to do it via inline script because i use the value in several scripts, so if i load the scripts in the head the variables are not going to be available. As Tim suggests I can make an ajax call  to receive the values, i'm going to try this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may very well work, but I think it's just as easy to generate inline javascript in the page itself. I assume the parameters may change on each request, so by putting them in the page itself, you save a request for each page view.

Comment: Same reply that i made in the first comments " I don't want to do it via inline script because i use the value in several scripts, so if i load the scripts in the head the variables are not going to be available", unless of course it can be done in some way. Thanks

Comment: Of course, the combined Javascript in your page and in the included scripts are treated as a single large script. The variables you declare are available in those scripts as well. The only thing you should worry about, is that the variables must be declared before any code that uses them is executed. If you make sure the inline code is the first script tag in your head, then you're always safe.

Comment: By the way, this is the method MediaWiki uses as well. Some user info is made available as an object (JSON notation) in the head of the page. Any scripts that are included add functionality through AJAX, using this data.

Answer (score -1):

Lets think about this - you are sending server variables to a browser

The browser is run by somebody not in your control.

You assume they will send those variables back faithly.

HERE IT BREAKS DOWN.

You receive those variables. AND YOU ASSUME THOSE VARIABLES HAVE NOT BEEN COMPRISED

So those variables go on with you not caring?

Comment: Who said anything about the variables being sent back to the server for storage?

Comment: "that returns all the values and stores them in javascript global variables to use them" - Guess they are going back to the server.

Comment: "Stores them in JavaScript" is pretty much the polar opposite of "going back to the server".

Comment: The values are never sent back to the server, they are just to be used in client-side

Comment: "returns all values" implies being set to the server.

Comment: "parameters.php returns all the values", i think it says that the php is "returning the values"

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like lets say:

```
<?php 
    $variable = "some variable that you need";
?>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
document.write("<?php echo $variable;?>")
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Yes i can print the values in the document but i don't want to use it inline

Comment: This answer will break the javascript if the variable contains a double quote.